# AttributeError: 'Product' object has no attribute 'filter'

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to access the link 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/2' in which I'm using a generic view(DetailsView) and in that view I want to use my custom model manager. But I'm getting the error which states AttributeError: 'Product' object has no attribute 'filter'.

I'm using python version3.8 and django version 2.2.6

```
# ModelManager
#-----------------------------------------------
class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_id(self,id):
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(id=id)
        if qs.count() == 1:
            return qs.first()
        return None



# View
#-----------------------------------------------
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    # queryset = Product.objects.all( )
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = self.request
        pk = self.kwargs.get("pk")
        instance = Product.objects.get_by_id(pk)
        if instance is None:
            raise Http404("Product Couldn't be found")
        return instance
```

### # Error

```
Internal Server Error: /products/2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py", line 106, in get
    self.object = self.get_object()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py", line 36, in get_object
    queryset = queryset.filter(pk=pk)
AttributeError: 'Product' object has no attribute 'filter'
[22/Oct/2019 18:51:56] "GET /products/2 HTTP/1.1" 500 75133
```

Comment: `get_queryset` expects a `QuerySet`, not an instance. You should override `get_object`.

Answer (score 1):

The [**`get_queryset(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset) expects a *queryset*, not an instance. You should override [**`get_object(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object) instead:

```
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = self.request
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        instance = Product.objects.get_by_id(pk)
        if instance is None:
            raise Http404('Product Couldn't be found')
        return instance
```

The reason that overriding the `get_queryset` fails is because if you return a single `Product` object, then the default `get_object` will call the `get_queryset`, and then call `.filter(..)` on that result. But a single `Product` of course has no `.filter(..)` method.

Note that it might be more efficient to implement your manager as:

```
class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_id(self,id):
        try:
            return self.get_queryset().get(id=id)
        except (self.model.DoesNotExist, self.model.MultipleObjectsReturned):
            return None
```

since here we will only make *one* query to the database, not multiple ones.